# Create item if not found and return old one if existing in dynamodb, in one call

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

In DynamoDb, is it possible to do a conditional put and return the old item if there already was a matching item?

I would like something like the following to create the row if the user does not already exist, and if it does exist, I want it to return the old item (with whatever name was there before). I.e., insert item if new, else just read existing item.

```
    await documentClient.put({
      TableName: 'table',
      Item: {
        userId: 'user0',
        name: 'smith',
      },
      ConditionExpression: 'attribute_not_exists(userId)',
    });
```

Is this possible to do in one call?

Answer (score 0):

Sort of.

If you use UpdateItem it will create or update the item. It only updates the fields that have changed however, so if your fields have not changed, then no update will be made. It will also create the item if you do not have it.

Using Conditional Items for this will return an ErrorCode if the condition fails `ConditionalCheckFailedException` - which would require an additional operation.

(I don't use the javascript SDK that much, more in python, so I'm not sure this is the correct version/page but here is some documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#updateItem-property )